# I am using lombok builder in Data Provider Class but i am getting Data provider mismatch

Tags: selenium-webdriver, lombok, builder, dataprovider, mismatch

This is my Provider method

```
@DataProvider(name = "loginDataSet")
    public static Object[][] loginSet() {
        return new Object[][]{
                {

                        String.valueOf(LoginProvider.builder()
                                .username(data.getUsername())
                                .password(data.getPassword())
                                .build())
                }
        };
    }
```

This is my Test Method

```
@Test(dataProvider = "loginDataSet", dataProviderClass = LoginData.class)
    public void loginAxis(String userValue, String userPassword) {
        new UserLogin(userValue,userPassword);
}
```

Getting following exception

```
org.testng.internal.reflect.MethodMatcherException: 
[public void Login.AxisLogin.loginAxis(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)] has no parameters defined but was found to be using a data provider (either explicitly specified or inherited from class level annotation).
Data provider mismatch
Method: loginAxis([java.lang.String arg0, java.lang.String arg1])
Arguments: [(java.lang.String) LoginProvider(username=863331712, password=Test@123)]
```

Please help me with the solution

I tried calling Data using Lombok builder for Selenium Data Provider getting method mismatch error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a Lombok issue.

See what the error says:

```
Data provider mismatch
Method: loginAxis([java.lang.String arg0, java.lang.String arg1])
Arguments: [(java.lang.String) LoginProvider(username=863331712, password=Test@123)]
```

So your **loginAxis** expects 2 strings: *userValue* and *userPassword*

But your *loginDataSet* DataProvider returns an array with the string representation of your *LoginProvider* instance.

As a result, the test expected 2 strings but received only one.

So you either have to change the data provider (whatever the 'data' object means in your case):

```
  @DataProvider(name = "loginDataSet")
    public static Object[][] loginSet() {
        return new Object[][]{
                {
    
                        data.getUsername(),
                        data.getPassword()
                }
        };
    }
```

Or you need to change the Test parameter to LoginProvider (and remove String.valueOf() from the data provider of course):

```
@Test(dataProvider = "loginDataSet", dataProviderClass = LoginData.class)
public void loginAxis(LoginProvider loginProvider) {
    new UserLogin(loginProvider.getUsername(), loginProvider.getPassword());
}
```